# Excel VBA: Workbooks.Open returns the wrong object

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2016 (don't remember it happening in earlier versions), I'm beginning to encounter issues where the Workbooks.Open command does not return the correct Workbook object. For example:

```
Dim wbkHelper as Workbook
Set wbkHelper = Workbooks.Open(filePath, ReadOnly:=true)
```

The Open command functions correctly - it opens the "filePath" file like it's supposed to - but wbkHelper ends up pointing to the completely wrong file, typically the ThisWorkbook object. The wbkHelper object is never reassigned to after that point in the code, so it's not something the code is doing. This only happens sometimes and can be difficult to reproduce, but it breaks the entire macro when it does happen.

I can think of numerous ways to work around this, but it shouldn't be necessary?  This is a core VBA function that's used all the time, and it's something you expect to just work.

EDIT:  This is easily reproducible, please see my comment @Marc.Meketon that follows @Phil Preen solution below.

Comment: Does `filePath` contain just the path or does it also include the file name as well (including the correct extension, such as `.xlsm` or `.xlsx`)?

Comment: I've never seen that behavior - I would have to guess there's something else going on.

Comment: I have seen that behaviour before - I think it was if the `Open` fails but there is an `On Error Resume Next` in play, or it might have been in the case when the file was already open when the `Open` statement was executed.

Comment: Can't replicate the issue at the moment though :(

Comment: Can you break it down further? What happens if your macro is just those two lines, along with a debug.print statement? Does it still break?

Comment: Well, hopefully this was much ado over nothing. I restarted the PC, and the issue hasn't recurred since then (shame on me for not trying the most obvious thing first!).  Still no idea what caused it though. It definitely happened the way I described - I have 10+ years experience as an Excel VBA developer, and I'm 100% confident in what I was witnessing. Oh well, chalk it up to Excel being Excel I guess!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I experienced this same issue today and resolved it by closing all workbooks and relaunching Excel.

Using Excel 2016 on Office 365.

```
Dim curWS As Worksheet
Dim usrWB As Workbook
Dim usrWS As Worksheet

Set curWS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set usrWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\user.xlsx")
Set usrWS = usrWB.Sheets("Users")
```

Was receiving a *Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range* at the set usrWS line.

I found that usrWB was not referencing the user.xlsx file but instead was referencing the workbook from the curWS line which did not have a worksheet named "Users" explaining the RTE.  I found this question and tried restarting Excel first before trying a reboot and the problem went away.

Comment: That's been my experience as well (ie, that restarting Excel fixes it).  Must just be some sort of memory/corruption "thing" within Excel.  I wish I knew what caused it in the first place. It seems to be a relatively uncommon issue, but causes some major headaches until you figure out why it's happening.

Answer (score 8):

I am seeing this with an old application written in VB6 that has been working for years, and users who are upgrading to Excel 2016 are starting to report problems. In my case it seems to be happening pretty consistently (seems to return a reference to one of the .xla addins). As the program has multiple Excel files open, and the user may also have other files open, closing and re-opening Excel every time it opens a new workbook is not a practical solution.

Until Microsoft acknowledge this as a fault in Excel, or someone can figure out what conditions cause the problem to occur, I would definitely recommend that you ignore the return value from the Workbooks.Open method, and instead use the filename to get the Workbook object reference from the Workbooks collection afterwards.

```
Dim wbkHelper as Workbook
Set wbkHelper = Workbooks.Open(filePath, ReadOnly:=true)
Set wbkHelper = Workbooks(filename) ' note filename needs to be filepath without the path
```

Comment: I am using the Excel build 1902... Not sure, but I believe that is Excel 2016.

I can reproduce the error easily.  Open up workbook AAAA.xlsx, Open up workbook BBBB.xlsm.  In BBBB.xlsm, in VBA, have `wb` be a Workbook object.  `set wb = Workbooks.Open(filepath_to_AAAA.xlsx, ReadOnly:=true)` `debug.print wb.name` and I get BBBB.xlsm, not AAAA.xlsm.

@Phil Preen answer works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the same thing I experienced.  My issue was when running a macro one user could not open a csv file (so no macros in the file he was trying to open) saved on a sharepoint location (in case it is relevant it had been mapped to a drive letter).  Other users had no issues with the same file accessed the same way.  This one user had the issue persist over a number of reboots over a number of weeks.  It was opening broken version of the file.

What I found was:

- an explorer view showed the correct timestamp on the file
- opening the file directly in excel it was still opening the broken version
- opening the file directly in word was also opening the broken version
- opening the file in notepad (which is not MS office) opened the correct version
- using command line `more` opened the correct version

What I did not find was that it was anything to do with offline or synced files (as suggested by google searches).

What fixed it was a "resolve" button (under menu File -> Info) that talks about the file having a more recent copy on sharepoint.
[image: screenshot from excel]

Clicked the button and all working.

Comment: why has this been marked down?